# javax.persistence @JoinColumn not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to join 2 tables (ManytoMany) and I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
> referencedColumnNames(planDate, planId, weekday) of
> com.MD.Medicine.Models.Meds.assignedMeds referencing
> com.MD.Medicine.Models.Plans not mapped to a single property

My entities,
Plans.java:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "plans")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "assignedMeds")
public class Plans {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PlansPKId plansPKId;

    @Column
    private String planName;

    @Column
    private String weekday;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Plan_Meds", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "planDate", referencedColumnName = "planDate"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "planId", referencedColumnName = "planId"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "weekday", referencedColumnName = "weekday"), }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private Set<Meds> assignedMeds = new HashSet<>();

}
```

PlansPKId.java (for Plans Model):

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class PlansPKId implements Serializable {

    private Date planDate; // format: yyyy-mm-dd
    private long planId;

  

}
```

Meds.java:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "meds")

public class Meds {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column
    private String category;

    @Column
    private int pillNumber;

    @Column
    private Date date;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "assignedMeds")
    private Set<Plans> plans = new HashSet<>();

}
```

When I join only with this:

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Plan_Meds", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "planDate", referencedColumnName = "planDate"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "planId", referencedColumnName = "planId"), }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private Set<Meds> assignedMeds = new HashSet<>();
```

It works properly, but if I had the column "weekday" I start getting the error. Am I not supposed to join them like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, basically, the purpose of `@JoinTable` is to create *an intermediate table* that **only** contains keys of each participant table.

```java
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Plan_Meds", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "planDate", referencedColumnName = "planDate"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "planId", referencedColumnName = "planId"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "weekday", referencedColumnName = "weekday"), }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private Set<Meds> assignedMeds = new HashSet<>();
```

In this case,

```
joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "planDate", referencedColumnName = "planDate"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "planId", referencedColumnName = "planId")}
```

will refer to the key of your `Plans` entity **plansPKId**, and

```
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")
```

will refer to the `Meds` entity's key **id**. Since **weekday** `@JoinColumn(name = "weekday", referencedColumnName = "weekday")`, it's not referring to any key, it should not be here.

---

In case you need to add some more fields in the join table, **manually** create your own join table and use @ManyToOne instead: [manytomany](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many#many-to-many-using-a-composite-key)